# Followers in twitter (tweepy)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to download my followers of twitter and the followers of my followers. T
The code seems to work but it doesn´t download all my followers. It downloads a portion and in this portion I think it works well. But why not all?

why is it?

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
"""
@author: Mik
"""
import csv 
import time 

import tweepy

# Copy the api key, the api secret, the access token and the access token secret from the relevant page on your Twitter app 

api_key = ''
api_secret = ''
access_token = '-'
access_token_secret = ''

# You don't need to make any changes below here # This bit authorises you to ask for information from Twitter 
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret) 
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret) 
# The api object gives you access to all of the http calls that Twitter accepts 
api = tweepy.API(auth) 

#User we want to use as initial node 
user=''


#This creates a csv file and defines that each new entry will be in a new line 
csvfile=open(user+'network2.csv', 'w') 
spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) 

#This is the function that takes a node (user) and looks for all its followers #and print them into a CSV file... and look for the followers of each follower... 
def fib(n,user,spamwriter):
    if n>0:
        #There is a limit to the traffic you can have with the API, so you need to wait 
        #a few seconds per call or after a few calls it will restrict your traffic 
        #for 15 minutes. This parameter can be tweeked 
        time.sleep(40) 

        #This is for private users that we wont be able to see their followers
        try:
            users=tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name = user, wait_on_rate_limit = True).items()
            for follower in users:
                spamwriter.writerow([user+';'+follower.screen_name]) 
                fib(n-1,follower.screen_name,spamwriter) 
                #n defines the level of autorecurrence

        except tweepy.TweepError:
                print("Failed to run the command on that user, Skipping...")



n=2
fib(n,user,spamwriter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly then you want to get ids of all followers of each of your followers.
Use logic like following, it will get you details of your 3000 followers per 15 minutes

```
import tweepy
#twitter credentials here---------------------------------------------------
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(your keys)
auth.set_access_token(your keys)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

iter1 = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name = 'your_screen_name',count = 200).pages()

for request in range(15):
      your_200_followers = next(iter1)
      for each_follower in your_200_followers:
               variable = each_follower.followers_ids
               #store the <list> variable somewhere
```